# Wait end of method inside another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to build a function that will delete unused files in the directory. I use Sequelize ORM in this method to get a recipe.

Here is my code

```
exports.deleteImagesNotUsed = (req, res) => {
 // Method who send me the result at the end
 const callBack = (listFiles, counter, counterfilesDeleted) => {
     if (listFiles.length === counter) {
      switch (counterfilesDeleted) {
       case 0:
        res.send({message: "No file deleted."});
        break;

       case 1:
        res.send({message: "One file deleted."});
        break;

       default:
        res.send({message: `${counterfilesDeleted} files deleted.`});
        break;
      }
     }
 };

 const getFiles = (() => {
  const directory = "./uploads";
  let counter = 0;
  let counterfilesDeleted = 0;
  fs.promises.readdir(directory) // Get all files in directory
  .then(files => {
   files.forEach(file => {
    if (file !== "no-image.jpg") {
     Recipe.findOne({ // Select * from Recipe where imageFileName = file
       where: {       // It's method from Sequelize ORM
        imageFileName: file
       }
      })
      .then(data => {
       if (data == null) {
        const path = `${directory}/${file}`;
        fs.unlinkSync(path); // Delete the file
        counterfilesDeleted++;
       }
      });
    }
    counter++;
    callBack(files, counter, counterfilesDeleted);
   });
  });
 })();
}
```

I would like to wait for the end of my method Recipe.findOne and its callback before go to `counter++` and `callBack(files, counter, counterfilesDeleted)`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Put that stuff inside the preceding `.then` - The `then` function after findOne gets executed precisely when you need.

Comment: Thanks James, that's works now. It was so easy, I'm ashamed to haven't found the solution

Comment: You can put that code inside another `.then` , but you are incrementing the counter outside `if` statement, If you put your code in another preceding  `.then` , then your counter will only be incremented when this `(file !== "no-image.jpg")` condition matches. Please check if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put that part in a then method:

```
 const getFiles = (() => {
  const directory = "./uploads";
  let counter = 0;
  let counterfilesDeleted = 0;
  fs.promises.readdir(directory) // Get all files in directory
  .then(files => {
   files.forEach(file => {
    if (file !== "no-image.jpg") {
     Recipe.findOne({ // Select * from Recipe where imageFileName = file
       where: {       // It's method from Sequelize ORM
        imageFileName: file
       }
      })
      .then(data => {
       if (data == null) {
        const path = `${directory}/${file}`;
        fs.unlinkSync(path); // Delete the file
        counterfilesDeleted++;
       }
      })
      .then(() => {
        counter++;
        callBack(files, counter, counterfilesDeleted);
      });
    }
   });
  });
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. I follow the comment of James and everything works.
Here is my code of my second method.

```
const getFiles = (() => {
  const directory = "./uploads";
  let counter = 0;
  let counterfilesDeleted = 0;
  fs.promises.readdir(directory) // Get all files in directory
  .then(files => {
   files.forEach(file => {
    if (file !== "no-image.jpg") {
     Recipe.findOne({ // Select * from Recipe where imageFileName = file
       where: {       // It's method from Sequelize ORM
        imageFileName: file
       }
      })
      .then(data => {
       if (data == null) {
        const path = `${directory}/${file}`;
        fs.unlinkSync(path); // Delete the file
        counterfilesDeleted++;
       }
       counter++;
       callBack(files, counter, counterfilesDeleted);
      });
    } else {
     counter++;
    }
   });
  });
 })();
```